# Stop process if condition is null and return message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a controller like this:

```
public ActionResult CargaCSV(HttpPostedFileBase archivo)
        {

            List<string[]> registros = new List<string[]>();
            confService = new ConfiguracionService();

            if (archivo.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                StreamReader sR = new StreamReader(archivo.InputStream);
                string linea;
                string resultado = "";

                var f = 0;

                while ((linea = sR.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (f == 0)
                    {
                        f++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String[] registros_ = linea.Split(',');
                        registros.Add(registros_);
                    }
                }
                sR.Close();

                ViewBag.Message = resultado;
                confService.GuardarMatrizCsv(registros,usuarioCaptura);
            }


            return Json(registros);
        }
```

As you can see I return result into div:

```
ViewBag.Message = resultado;
```

View:

```
<div class="" style="height: 150px; overflow: auto; margin-bottom:10px;">
<pre id="resultado">@ViewBag.Message</pre>
</div>
```

That I want to do is to cancel all proccess if `(archivo.ContentLength > 0)` return null and return:  `ViewBag.Message = "you need attach file to load it";` and stop all process

How can I achieve this?

Update:

I call `CargaCSV` method with ajax call:

```
 $("#btnCargarCsv").on("click", function () {

        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("archivo", $("#archivo")[0].files[0]);

        $.ajax({
            "type": "POST",
            "url": "/Configuracion/CargaCSV",
            "contentType": false,
            "processData": false,
            "data": data,
            success: function (s) {
                var result = $("#resultado");
                result.text("");
                result.append("<table>");
                result.append("<tr>");
                result.append("<th> Unidad </th>");
                result.append("<th> CR Mínimo </th>");
                result.append("<th> CR Máximo </th>");
                result.append("<th> % Mínimo </th>");
                result.append("<th> % Máximo </th>");
                result.append("</tr>");

                for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                    var val = s[i];
                    result.append("<tr>");
                    result.append("<td> " + val[0] + " </td>");
                    result.append("<td> " + val[1] + " </td>");
                    result.append("<td> " + val[2] + " </td>");
                    result.append("<td> " + val[3] + " </td>");
                    result.append("<td> " + val[4] + " </td>");
                    result.append("</tr>");
                }
                result.append("</table>");
            }
        });
    });
```

So here I append data into table and show data into pre html tag "resultado"

Comment: Which part is not working? You need to return View instead of Json. For example, `return View(registros);`

Comment: @Win  Now it's workiln well, I want to add validation if `(archivo.ContentLength > 0)` return null, and display that validation into `@ViewBag.Message` to receive in view

Comment: How did you call CargaCSV action method?

Comment: I update my quesion with ajax call @Win

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your returning a `JsonResult`, not a `ViewResult`, so setting a `ViewBag` property is pointless (`ViewBag` is for passing data to a `View`) and your

```
<pre id="resultado">@ViewBag.Message</pre>
```

element will only ever display the initial value of `ViewBag.Message` when the page is first rendered.

You need to return the message in your `JsonResult` and test it in the ajax success method.

Change the controller code to return different values based on your condition

```
public ActionResult CargaCSV(HttpPostedFileBase archivo)
{
    if (archivo.ContentLength =  0)
    {
        string message = "you need attach file to load it";
        return Json( new { message = message });
    }
    .... // your code to process the file
    return Json(new { registros = registros });
}
```

and change the code in the success callback to test the result

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data.message) {
        $('#resultado').text(data.message);
    } else if (data.registros) {
        var result = $("#resultado");
        ....
        for (var i = 0; i < data.registros.length; i++) {
            var val = data.registros[i];
            ....
        }
        result.append("</table>");
    }
}
```

As a side note, you could simplify your script by generating the `<table>` and its headings (which should be in a `<thead>` element) in the view (and style it using `display: none;`and just add the `<tr>` elements inside its `<tbody>` element (and then show/hide the table in the success callback), for example

```
<table id="resultstable" style="display:none">
    <thead>
        ....
    </thead>
    <tbody id="results"></tbody>
<table>
```

Script

```
var table = $('#resultstable');
var results = $('#results');
var message = $('#resultado');

$('btnCargarCsv').on('click', function () {
    ....
    $.ajax({
        ....
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.message) {
                message.text(data.message);
                table.hide();
            } else if (data.registros) {
                results.empty(); //remove any existing rows
                table.show();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.registros.length; i++) {
                    var val = data.registros[i];
                    var row = $('<tr></tr>');
                    for(int j = 0; j < val.length; j++) {
                        row.append($('<td></td>').text(val[j]));
                    }
                    results.append(row);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

In addition, you should be testing if the value of the file input is `null` before making the ajax call (and cancel the ajax call and display the message if it is) to prevent an unnecessary call to the server.